# Unable to get longitude and latitude on my android device

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps

I have an application that displays the GPS longitude and latitude. It works if i use the LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER it display the longitude and latitude of the network. But when i use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER it does not display anything. But when i use google maps it can point where i am. What does google maps do to get my location? I need to get the Longitude and Latitude of my device.

Here is my code

```
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

double glat;
double glng;


LocationListener glocListener;

TextView longitudetv;
TextView latitudetv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    longitudetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    longitudetv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    latitudetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    latitudetv.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//This is for Lat lng which is determine by your device GPS
    public class MyLocationListenerGPS implements LocationListener  
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            glat = loc.getLatitude();
            glng = loc.getLongitude();

            //Setting the GPS Lat, Lng into the textView

            longitudetv.setText("" + glng);
            latitudetv.setText("" + glat);


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
        LocationManager locman = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        if(locman.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            tv.setText("Started!");
            latitudetv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            longitudetv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            locman   = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            glocListener = new MyLocationListenerGPS();
            locman.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                1000 * 1,  // 1 Sec        
                       0, // 0 meter   
                       glocListener);

        }
        else{
            tv.setText("There is no GPS Connection");
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "GPS is Disabled.Please enable GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }

    }

}



}
```

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.willardcuizon.adaptivedgps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:debuggable="false">
    <activity
        android:name="com.willardcuizon.adaptivedgps.Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you set the correct permission in the manifest file?

Comment: yup no problem in the manifest, im just confused why google maps can see my location and my app cant? But when i use NETWORK_PROVIDER instead of GPS_PROVIDER it gives me my network location.

Comment: Are you inside a building?

Comment: Show your manifest file.

Comment: yes i am inside my house, but even if i am inside my house i use google maps, the google maps application can still see my location.

Comment: Google maps is probably showing your lastKnownLocation, and then improves it by Network Provider, since you are inside a building.

Comment: hmmm so i can get longitude and latitude by using lastKnownLocation? one question anyway i can do all of this using Network Provider?

Comment: Network provider can give u locations inside a building, and you can use LastKnownLocation at startup, and start updating. My advice is to start listening for both GPS and Network, and replace with the location that has the best accuracy, you should also filter for timestamps in case this is too old!

Comment: if you want to use "GPS_PROVIDER" then you will require open sky or near window location, while in "NETWORK_PROVIDER" you will get locations even if you are in basement as it fetches location details from network provider, while in case of "GPS_PROVIDER" it fetches location detail from Satelite so you must require open sky.

Comment: thanks for all your tips and suggestions guys, i literally just made this app about 3 hours ago and had no experience in android development guys. Thanks for all the info

Comment: it worked i just went out for a couple of minutes and it worked without network provider xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yes i am inside my house, but even if i am inside my house i use
>   google maps, the google maps application can still see my location

The problem is Google Maps is using the [LocationClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html), which is able to switch providers. If no GPS provider is reachable it will switch to a Network provider. The LocationManager isn't able to do this switch automatically. Therefor you have to handle this switching yourself or you use the LocationClient too, which would be the recommanded way. Here's the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) of the docs and inside your SDK is a sample code at `yoursdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps` which should help you how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is required that you use the permission to access GPS in you manifest file, here it is, if you haven't yet added

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Now that you have this permission, next thing that I find missing is MyLocationListenerGPS should extend Service (since location is a service). You can check this link which explains in details how to implement it.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), [Location APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)